# Massive amount of groupboxes visually stacked, how to better organize them?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: 30grouboxes]

It's pretty much like that. I have nearly 30 group boxes to organize, and most stack over themselves and are just visually enabled or disabled accordingly to the combo box in the top. I know that in `Form1.designer.cs` I can manually input their location, but that isn't helping much. Is there any tip on how to work best with this? I also tried to increase the size of the window, but its not enough.

Edit:
I'm following the accepted answer, [image: multiplegroupboxes]

Is there a way to move them and keep them exactly in their relative position? 
Edit 2: yes there is: just create a panel in a cleaner area, move and adjust the desired groupboxes in the panel, then move the panel into the tab, and instead of seting the parent of the group box, set the parent of the panel, for example

```
  panel1.Parent = tabPage3;
```

the groupboxes will be in their relative place :)

Comment: Are you asking _what_ would be a better design, or _how_ to implement it in C# Winforms? The former question would be a better fit for http://ux.stackexchange.com/, I guess.

Comment: neither, they are implemented, but since some of them work together, whey they are stacked up, i cant properly organize their location. Anyways i connected the pc to a 1900x1200 screen and with increased window size i could fix it. But i came with a bigger problem, some of them aren't showing up when the program runs

Comment: There is a control called FlowLayoutPanel. You could use it to support 'fluid' layout.

Comment: Replace each set of RadioButtons in a GroupBox with a single drop-down ComboBox control. Easier to manage, and much better UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hidden `Tab` control with enough pages and move the `GroupBoxes` there.

When your logic wants to show one of them on your target container, a TabPage, judging from your screenshot, and hide another one you would do something like this:

```
groupBox2.Parent = yourTargetContainer;  // bring it out of the hidden Tab
groupBox1.Parent = hidden_tabPage1;      // hide it in a page of the hidden Tab
```

Here the yourTargetContainer is the container that will hold the GroupBoxes at a certain Positions. All the controls inside the GroupBoxes will go with the box as usual.

Since you'll need them at various Positions you can add a Tag to each GroupBox to hold its Location on yourTargetContainer :

```
groupBox1.Tag = new Point(250, 40);
groupBox2.Tag = new Point(250, 40);
groupBox3.Tag = new Point(250, 90);
// ...
```

and use it to put it in the right place:

```
groupBox2.Parent = yourTargetContainer ;    
groupBox2.Location = (Point)groupBox2.Tag;
```

That way you have them all easily accessible in the designer where you can fine tune them. It will help to figure out a grid layout where they shall go..

Will the users be able to work with those changing input controls, though? And do they all have the big screens?

Comment: Trying to solve this i came with a more serious problem, some of the groupboxes aren't even showing up, altough the code is correctly, they only show up when i move them out of the stack, any idea why this is happening? Also, do i need any kind of special control to "hide" a tab?

Comment: You simply set `visible=false` in the designer. Note: I mean an __additional__ Tab control, not pages on the one you have; tabPages can't easily be hidden.  - As for the groupboxes that won't show: Could it be that you moved them __into__ rather than __onto__ the others? This is tricky because you need to use the keyboard; if you use the mouse any control will go into a container you move it over. All this will go away whan you separate them into tabs of their own, either one Groupbox per page or maybe even two or more.. once you have found them, of course ;-)

Comment: thank you very much, it's a great mechanism I basically can organize them, and then move them in and out of the tabs when i want them to show up

Comment: Exactly. BTW: The same mechanism would, should you ever need it, also help to 'hide' a `TabPage`.